# How To Change Image And Link On Click As Toggle Function?

Tags: javascript, css, html, anchor

I want a Pure JavaScript code that will change an image and also its link to another image and another link on same place as toggle function. I have a web page and I have **Anchors Links** button as `<a href="#DIV2"><img src="DownArrow.png"/></a>` and I want that after clicking on this image, first it will lead you to the DIV2 and then it will change the code to `<a href="#DIV1"><img src="UpArrow.png"/></a>`. How to do this using pure JavaScript? Waiting for perfect reply and code?

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan I tried many codes but all are changing images. I want to change links also.

Comment: @chandu Ok. Here I have [http://jsfiddle.net/TM9ap/](http://jsfiddle.net/TM9ap/). Now read me question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
var link = document.querySelector('#arrow a');
link.onclick = function() {
    var image = document.querySelector('#arrow a img');
    if(this.href.slice(-1) === '1') {
        this.href = '#DIV2';
        image.src = 'https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/nuvola2/48x48/actions/1uparrow.png';
    } else {
        this.href = '#DIV1';
        image.src = 'https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/nuvola2/48x48/actions/1downarrow.png';
    }
}
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/TM9ap/7/

Note that I've changed the `href` attribute in the link to `#DIV1` like this `<a href="#DIV1">`

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<title></title>
<head></head>
<body>
<a href = "#DIV1" style="color:BLACK;" onclick="execute();">Click me 
    <img src="UpArrow.png" />
</a>
<div id="DIV1" ></div>

<div id="DIV2" ></div>  
<script>


function execute()
{

if ( document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].getAttribute("href")==="#DIV1"){
    var img = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
    img.setAttribute("src","DownArrow.png");
    img.parentNode.setAttribute("href","#DIV2");
}
else 
{


    var img = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
    img.setAttribute("src","UpArrow.png");
        img.parentNode.setAttribute("href","#DIV1");
}

}




</script> 

</body>
</html>
```